# RegEx: Match only one element in xml structure

Tags: regex

I have this XML-structure where I would like to match the individual data-elements elements that have the `###DoNotUse###` string inside.

In the example, it should match the data elements `C` and `E`.

But my RegEx also matches all data-elements before the matches that I require, meaning `A+B+C` instead of just `C`, and `D+E` instead of just `E`.

I appreciate your help very much.

My RegEx is:

```
<data(.*?)###DoNotUse###(.*?)</data>
```

The example data is:

```
<data name="A">
    <value>A</value>
<comment>Bla Bla</comment>
</data>
<data name="B">
    <value>B</value>
</data>
<data name="C">
    <value>###DoNotUse###</value>
    <comment>Bla Bla</comment>
</data>
<data name="D">
    <value>D</value>
    <comment>Bla Bla</comment>
</data>
<data name="E">
    <value>###DoNotUse###</value>
</data>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576

Comment: It might be possible, but frankly, it's a pain in the ass. don't go down this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
(?s)<data name="([^"]*)">(?:(?!data).)*DoNotUse
```

The `(?s)` is for single line mode. You can find the demonstration and explanations [HERE: DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/V7rUdv/1/)

Comment: That seems to do the trick after some minor modification and points me into the right direction. Thank you very much!